# twitpic API GSTwitPicEngine error while setAccessToken

Tags: cocoa-touch, api, ios4, twitter-oauth, twitpic

I tried to use GSTwitPicEngine class https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine for sharing image on twitter
but its giving error

As we have to set `[twitpicEngine setAccessToken:token];`
if I am right, I am using `_accessToken` of class `SA_OAuthTwitterEngine` as token

`_accessToken` was private in class `SA_OAuthTwitterEngine`, I set it to public and also

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) OAToken *accessToken;
@synthesize accessToken = _accessToken;
```

and then in action

```
twitPicEngine = [GSTwitPicEngine twitpicEngineWithDelegate:self];
[twitPicEngine setAccessToken:twitterObj.accessToken];
[twitPicEngine uploadPicture:[shareDict objectForKey:@"image"] withMessage:[shareDict objectForKey:@"image_msg"]];
```

But Application getting crash while setAccessToken with log

```
-[OAToken parameters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6327e30
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OAToken parameters]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6327e30'
```

Please help if you able to find any thing wrong

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, GSTwitPicEngine is not using the same version of oauth-consumer than the fabulous Twitter+Oauth library (SAOAuthTwitterEngine). I assume you are using that library for posting messages to twitter.

The crash is because OAToken from Twitter+Oauth doesn´t implement the "parameters" method.

Today I spent the entire morning tweaking the several libraries to avoid crashes.
Here you can download a sample project I created for posting a twitpic photo to twitter with a message.

[TestTwitpic](http://www.mediafire.com/?dq9urci4uyvfd34)

The project has all the latest versions of all libraries from github.

**Instructions for making my TestTwitpic project work**:

In TestTwitpic-Prefix.pch set the variables for:

```
#define kTwitterOAuthConsumerKey @""
#define kTwitterOAuthConsumerSecret @""
#define kTwitPicAPIKey @""
```

In RootViewController you can change these lines to your needs. To change the photo:

```
//change [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"] for whatever UIImage you want to upload
//change @"my photo" for whatever title you want for your photo in twitpic website
[twitpicEngine uploadPicture:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"] withMessage:@"my photo"];
```

and this one to change message sent to twitter:

```
//I post to twitter the title of the photo and the twitpic url but you can post whatever you want
[engine sendUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[[response objectForKey:@"request"] userInfo] objectForKey:@"message"], [[response objectForKey:@"parsedResponse"] objectForKey:@"url"]]];
```

**If you want to create your own project based on this sample. Do the following:**

1. Import into your project (drag and drop) the Twitpic folder with all the libraries that are inside.
2. Add these frameworks to your project:

   - CoreGraphics
   - libz.1.2.3
   - libxml2
   - MobileCoreServices
   - SystemConfiguration
   - CFNetwork
   - Security
3. In Build Settings add "$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2" to the "Header Search Paths" (mark it as recursive)
4. In Build Settings add -lxml2 to "Other linker flags"

**If you want to know what I did for fixing the libraries, I will tell you more or less what I remember I did:**

1. Import Twitter+Oauth, GSTwitPicEngine, OARequestHeader, TouchJSON, and ASIHTTPRequest libraries.
2. Set `GSTwitPicEngine` to use `TouchJSON` instead of `YAJL`.
3. Added the category NSString+URLEncoding from oauth-consumer github project as **OARequestHeader** was missing it.
4. Modified all occurrences of NSDictionary* foo = [toke parameters] inside **OARequestHeader** with the line:

   - `NSDictionary *foo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[token key] forKey:@"oauth_token"];`
5. Created a method getAccessToken in SAOAuthTwitterEngine to return the private _accessToken variable.
6. In requestFinished: inside GSTwitPicEngine

   - change the line:

     - `response = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:responseString error:&error];`
   - with the line:

     - `response = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:[responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:&error];`
   - as GSTwitPicEngine wrongly assumed deserialize:error: method accepts an NSString instead of an NSData.

Comment: request getting failed continuously...TestTwitpic[2180:207] TwitPic failed to upload: {
    errorDescription = "Request failed.";
    request = "<ASIFormDataRequest: 0x601d400>";

any help

Comment: Sorry for late response.. I was busy in other task...I am not able to run sample

Comment: Thank you for the sample code.. Friends If you got any errors add the libz.dylib... It works like a charm :)

Comment: @Monitus, Where to set the "Access token" and "Access token secret"?

Comment: it's get me error 2012-07-05 19:18:22.380 TestTwitpic[8577:f803] DATA: (null)
2012-07-05 19:18:40.648 TestTwitpic[8577:f803] Authenicated for (null)
2012-07-05 19:18:40.649 TestTwitpic[8577:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

You can set Access token & Access Secret for twitpic after getting from twitter engine i.e

SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m

- (void) setAccessToken: (OAServiceTicket *) ticket withData: (NSData *) data

Create object of "GSTwitPicEngine.m" class in "SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m" & pass Access token & Access Secret to "GSTwitPicEngine.m" and set delegate methods of "GSTwitPicEngine.m" in "SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m"

And one more change...

must cross check URLEncoding while genrating OAuth Header i.e

[requestHeader generateRequestHeaders]

this will be according to "OAuthConsumer" classes in Twitter Library