# Tweeting from Cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I need to integrate Twitter into my Cocoa application.

I tried `MGTwitterEngine` class: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/

However I got several errors when I attached files to my project: `yajl_parse.h`, `OAToken.h` and `CJSONDeserializer.h` needed and I don't know where to find them:

[image]

Can you suggest me how to make `MGTwitterEngine` working or another way to integrate Twitter into my Cocoa app?

Comment: Can you show the errors here ?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my post

Answer (score 1):

one of the Main reasons for getting the errors in `libxml/xmlreader.h`..

-> Go to `Build settings` search for `Header Search Paths` add this `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`

```
Edit:
```

You can download the sample project from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591562/twitpic-api-gstwitpicengine-error-while-setaccesstoken)..  and add the libz.dylib framework... It works nicely...

Comment: It fixed problem with `libxml/xmlreader.h` , but how to fix `yajl_parse.h` and `OAToken.h`?

Comment: This sample project is adopted for iOS, not for OSX project

Comment: No, I still need `yajl_parse.h`, `OAToken.h` and `CJSONDeserializer.h`, look a screenshot in my post. I added lybxml2.dylib, it helped only with `xmlreader.h`

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338496/mgtwitterengine-for-iphone-sdk-errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7651/discussion-between-aravindhanarvi-and-ilya-blokh)